# Using cut() and quantile() to bucket continuous columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following generated df with ages and weights

```
df = data.frame(
    Age = sample(18:98, 1000, replace = TRUE),
    Weight = sample(80:250, 10000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I want to alter the continuous columns by creating buckets based on the quantiles (25%, 50%, 75%. This can be done like so:

```
> quantile(df$Age, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
25% 50% 75% 
 39  58  78
```

However, I want to use the cut function using these quantiles (25%, 50%, 75%)

How can I do this? I want the output to transform to something like this, where any continuous variable is converted to buckets based on the quantile (25%, 50%, 75%)

```
Age          Weight
(17.9,44.7]  (137,193]
(44.7,71.3]  (137,193]
(71.3,98.1]  (79.8,137]
(44.7,71.3]  (193,250]
(17.9,44.7]  (79.8,137]
```

Comment: (1) Your code is missing a comma, please test your own code before posting a question. (2) Please use `set.seed` before you use random numbers so that we can try to reproduce your random numbers (we cannot). (3) Given that your `Age` should be binned into `39,58,78`, where do the expected ranges for `Age` come from?

Comment: If you need something more heavy duty than just using the output of `quantile` in `cut`, take a look at the `classInt` package, which has a function `classIntervals` that breaks continuous variables into bins based on one of several different functions.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass your quantiles as the second argument to `cut`, though add a 0 and 1 quantile so that your cuts have lower and upper bounds. (i.e. `c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)`, which can be concisely written as `0:4 / 4`)

**Tidyverse version**

```r
library(dplyr)

as_tibble(df) %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), .fn = function(x) cut(x, quantile(x, 0:4/4))))
#> # A tibble: 10,000 x 2
#>    Age     Weight   
#>    <fct>   <fct>    
#>  1 (18,38] (80,121] 
#>  2 (78,98] (121,165]
#>  3 (18,38] (121,165]
#>  4 (58,78] (208,250]
#>  5 (58,78] (165,208]
#>  6 (78,98] (80,121] 
#>  7 (38,58] (165,208]
#>  8 (58,78] (80,121] 
#>  9 (38,58] (165,208]
#> 10 (58,78] (121,165]
#> # ... with 9,990 more rows
```

---

**Base R version**

```r
df$Age <- cut(df$Age, quantile(df$Age, 0:4/4))
df$Weight <- cut(df$Weight, quantile(df$Weight, 0:4/4))
```

Comment: Hi I actually want to do quantiles (0.25, 0.5, 0.75) but when i do this `df %>% mutate(across(everything(), .fn = function(x) cut(x, quantile(x, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75)))))` I get <NA> values. Do you know why that is? Also I generally don't want to mutate across everything because I want to generalize to where a dataframe may not have all continuous values.

Comment: @Eisen if your lowest break is the 25% quantile then anything below that will not be included, and will become `NA`. Similarly, anything higher than the 75% centile will be `NA` if you set these breaks. That's why I suggested adding the 0 and 1 centiles - this will split your data into the 4 correct quantiles without excluding the highest and lowest quartiles. For example the 0-25% quantile, the 25-50% quartile, the 50-75% quartile and the 75-100% quartile

Comment: @Eisen see my update to do this per column in base R

Comment: This is cool but not exactly what i want. `quantile(df$Age, probs = c(0.25,0.5,0.75))` would break out the custom quantile I want..Trying to figure out how to incorporate it within `cut()`. So everything  25%  or under is considered 25% and everything 75% or over is considered 75%

Comment: @Eisen if you want every observation to be binned, the lowest and highest values of the observation must be within the highest and lowest value of `breaks`. Putting in your quantiles would keep only the second and fourth quantile. Is that what you want? If not, could you explain what you're trying to achieve in a bit more detail? Thanks

Comment: That's what I think I want.. could you show me that solution with `breaks`? Thank you

Comment: @Eisen it's just `df$Age <- cut(df$Age, quantile(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))` and `df$Weight <- cut(df$Weight, quantile(c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))`. The values bellow the 25th centile and above the 75th centile will appear as `NA`, and everyone else will be in one of two bins: the 25-50th centile bin or the 50-75th centile bin.

Comment: I'm gonna keep your original solution, however, it gives NAs. I see one where the Age is 18 and it's converted to <NA>. This is because the levels are: (18,37] (37,58.5] (58.5,79] (79,98]

Comment: @Eisen you can include the 18 year olds if you use `cut(df$Age, quantile(df$Age, 0:4/4), include.lowest = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

My `santoku` package has `chop_quantiles()`:

```r
library(santoku)
df[] <- apply(df, 2, chop_quantiles, 0:4/4)
```

or even simpler:

```r
df[] <- apply(df, 2, chop_equally, 4)
```

The empty brackets are a trick which keeps `df` as a data.frame.

If you want the raw values in your labels, you can do:

```r
df[] <- apply(df, 2, chop_equally, 4, labels = lbl_intervals(raw = TRUE))
```